# LookupRecord Data Block in Access 2010 not accepting SQL

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-office, ms-access-2010

In all the documentation I can find (including this [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195882%28v=office.14%29.aspx)), the LookupRecord data block is described as

> A string that identifies the record to operate on. The *In* argument can contain the name of the table, a select query, or a **SQL statement**.

Emphasis mine on "SQL statement"; I'd expect to be able to drop a straight `SELECT` into the *In* field, especially a simple query like `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM myTable ORDER BY id` but no matter what I put in that field, it gives me a little error balloon stating "The SQL statement is invalid".

There is nothing funky going on, it's not a linked table, it's a .accdb file, etc.

Does the LookupRecord simply only accept table names or Queries?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the answer comes to me immediately after this is posted.

### **Answer:**

When using SQL in a macro, you must always encapsulate your object names with square brackets.

For example:

Good: `SELECT [myTable].[myColumn] FROM [myTable] ORDER BY [myTable].[effectiveDate]`

Bad: `SELECT myTable.myColumn FROM myTable ORDER BY myTable.effectiveDate`

Comment: Of note, it appears that you still can't use TOP 1 - is this implied by the nature of LookupRecord?